# I need to replace this micro USB but can't find a female 6 wire

Tags: battery-charging

I need to replace this female micro USB but am not finding one with 6 pins. It appears there are 4 pins together then 2 more that are separated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: micro-USB *always* has five pins. Could one of them be the shield?

Comment: Can you take a better picture? The relevant area is just 1-2 % of this picture.

Comment: here is a better picture ..having trouble taking a good magnified picture. There are two outside wires that appear to be uninsulated and plugged into a oval pc of plastic, then the 4 insulated wires on the left side of the picture

Comment: Do you want to tell us what is the equipment in which this is used? how it used with some pictures? Is something similar (https://www.elecbee.com/en-13672-waterproof-level-ipx8-micro-usb-connector-b-type-female-5p-smt-with-waterproof-ring-rating-3a)could be used or want exact same?

Comment: this connector is from a Arlo security camera, the female micro usb is on the outside of the camera with the 6 pin connector on the other end inside the camera

Answer (score 0):

I would search by application. E.g. "Samsung S3 charging port", replacing "Samsung S3" with whichever phone or tablet this connector has been taken from.

Appears likely to be a "xusb" connector which is the collective name for about 30 different connectors made by Motorola and Samsung to provide enhanced capabilities for their phones similar to the Apple 30-pin and Lightning connectors.

Comment: It is from an arlo security camera, I have done some of those types of searches. I am not a fan of arlo so trying to not spend alot of money on it. I think I may have to buy a used camera to get this connector without spending a lot of money on it